# Groupoid-valued presheaf as a colimit of representables

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

Is there a specific way to see a presheaf of groupoids as a colimit of representables ? As you can understand I'm looking for a similar result to the well-known fact that presheaves of sets are colimits of representables.
In my case what could be the representables ?

Best

Comment: Obviously, no: colimits of discrete groupoids are still discrete groupoids. So you have to extend/change the notion of colimit.

Comment: @ZhenLin: I agree, this is the reason why I said "what could be the representables" since they are definitely not the usual home sets seen as discrete groupoids. Not sure you have to change the notion of colimit but you have to change what one means by representables.

Comment: No. The meaning of representable is fixed. But you can consider other kind ls of colimits in this setting, e.g. weighted colimits.

Comment: yes, considering enriched homs (enriched in Gpd here) and weighted colimits is likely the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a Bénabou cosmos (= complete and cocomplete symmetric monoidal closed category). Then, for any small $\mathcal{V}$-category $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$, the $\mathcal{V}$-category $[\underline{\mathcal{A}}^\mathrm{op}, \underline{\mathcal{V}}]$ is the free completion of $\underline{\mathcal{A}}$ under weighted $\mathcal{V}$-colimits. Indeed, given a $\mathcal{V}$-presheaf $P : \underline{\mathcal{A}}^\mathrm{op} \to \underline{\mathcal{V}}$, we have the following formula,
$$P \cong P \star_{\underline{\mathcal{A}}} Y$$
where $Y : \underline{\mathcal{A}} \to [\underline{\mathcal{A}}^\mathrm{op}, \underline{\mathcal{V}}]$ is the Yoneda embedding and $W \star_{\underline{\mathcal{A}}} F$ denotes the $\mathcal{V}$-colimit of a diagram $F : \underline{\mathcal{A}} \to \underline{\mathcal{C}}$ weighted by $W : \underline{\mathcal{A}}^\mathrm{op} \to \underline{\mathcal{V}}$.

In particular, this applies when $\mathcal{V} = \mathbf{Grpd}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is any ordinary small category. So every presheaf of groupoids is indeed a *weighted* colimit of representables.